# How do I erase elements from STL containers?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, std

How do I erase elements from STL containers, having a specified *value*, or satisfying some *condition*?

Is there a single common or uniform way of doing that for different kinds of containers?

Comment: Could be good for the C++faq.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore How does this work in general anyway? Is this usually decided by the community based on in-comment discussion, or can everybody just decide to tag this `c++-faq` (well, of course one can, but maybe this is regarded bad etiquette, since this tag is a bit more strictly content controlled). Or should one just tag it and make it the community's responsiblity to remove the tag if they don't agree.

Comment: @ChristianRau it's generally discussed in [the lounge](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a single *uniform* interface or pattern for erasing elements from STL containers.
But three behaviors emerge:

### std::vector Pattern

To erase elements that fulfill a certain condition from a **`std::vector`**, a common technique is the so called [**erase-remove idiom**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom).

If `v` is an instance of `std::vector`, and we want to erase elements with value `x` from the vector, code like this can be used:

```
// Erase elements having value "x" from vector "v"
v.erase( std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), x), v.end() );
```

If the criterion to be fulfilled for erasing elements is more complex than the simple *"element to be erased == x"*, the `std::remove_if()` algorithm can be used instead of `std::remove()`:

```
// Erase elements matching "erasing_condition" from vector "v"
v.erase( std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), erasing_condition), v.end() );
```

where `erasing_condition` is a unary predicate, that can be expressed in several forms: e.g. it can be a **`bool`-returning function** taking vector element type as input (so if the returned value is `true`, the element will be erased from the vector; if it's `false`, it won't); or it can be expressed *in-line* as a **lambda**; it can be a [**functor**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses); etc.

(Both `std::remove()` and `std::remove_if()` are generic algorithms from `<algorithm>` header.)

Here is a clear explanation [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom):

> The `algorithm` library provides the `remove` and `remove_if`
>   algorithms for this. Because these algorithms operate on a range of
>   elements denoted by two forward iterators, they have no knowledge of
>   the underlying container or collection. Thus, no elements are actually
>   removed from the container. Rather, all elements which don't fit the
>   remove criteria are brought together to the front of the range, in the
>   same relative order. The remaining elements are left in a valid, but
>   unspecified state. When this is done, `remove` returns an iterator
>   pointing one past the last unremoved element.
>
> To actually eliminate elements from the container, `remove` is combined
>   with the container's `erase` member function, hence the name
>   "erase-remove idiom".

Basically, `std::remove()` and `std::remove_if()` compact the elements that do *not* satisfy the erasing criteria to the front of the range (i.e. to the beginning of the `vector`), and then `erase()` actually eliminates the remaining elements from the container.

This pattern applies also to other containers like **`std::deque`**.

### std::list Pattern

To erase elements from a **`std::list`**, simple **`remove()` and `remove_if()` methods** are available:

```
// Erase elements having value "x" from list "l"
l.remove( x )

// Erase elements satisfying "erasing_condition" from list "l"
l.remove_if( erasing_condition );
```

(Where `erasing_condition` is a unary predicate, with the same characteristics discussed for `std::remove_if()` in the above section.)

The same pattern can be applied to similar containers, like **`std::forward_list`**.

### Associative Containers (e.g. std::map, std::set, ...) Pattern

*Associative containers* like **`std::map`**, **`std::set`**, **`std::unordered_map`**, etc. follow the common pattern described here:

1. If the erasing condition is a simple key-matching (i.e. *"erase the element 
   having key x"*), then a simple **`erase()` method** can be called:

   ```
   // Erase element having key "k" from map "m":
   m.erase( k );
   ```
2. If the erasing condition is more complex, and is expressed by some custom 
   unary predicate (e.g. *"erase all odd elements"*), then a `for` loop can be used
   (with an explicit erasing condition checking in loop body, and call to `erase(iterator)` method):

   ```
   //
   // Erase all elements from associative container "c", satisfying "erasing_condition":
   //
   for (auto it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); /* "it" updated inside loop body */ )
   {
       if ( erasing_condition(*it) )
       {   
           // Erase the element matching the specified condition 
           // from the associative container.
           it = c.erase(it);

           // Note:
           // erase() returns an iterator to the element 
           // that follows the last element removed, 
           // so we can continue the "for" loop iteration from that position.
       }
       else
       {
           // Current element does _not_ satisfy erasing condition,
           // so we can just move on to the next element.
           ++it;
       }       
   }
   ```

### The Need for a Unified Approach

As it can be noted from the above analysis, unfortunately there isn't a uniform common approach for erasing elements from STL containers.

The following table summarizes the aforementioned patterns:

> ```
> ----------------+------------------------------------------             
>    Container    |            Erasing Pattern
> ----------------+------------------------------------------                
>                 |
>  vector         |    Use erase-remove idiom.
>  deque          |
>                 |
> ----------------+------------------------------------------               
>                 |
>  list           |    Call remove()/remove_if() methods.
>  forward_list   |
>                 |
> ----------------+------------------------------------------  
>                 |
>  map            |    Simple erase(key) method call, 
>  set            |    or 
>  unordered_map  |    loop through the container,
>  multimap       |    and call erase(iterator) on matching
>                 |    condition.
>  ...            |
>                 |
> ----------------+------------------------------------------
> ```

Writing different specific code based on the particular container is error-prone, hard to maintain, hard to read, etc.

However, it's possible to write function templates with common names (e.g. `erase()` and `erase_if()`) *overloaded* for different container types, and embed the aforementioned pattern implementations in those functions.
So, the client can simply call those `erase()` and `erase_if()` generic functions, and the compiler will dispatch the call to proper implementation (at *compile time*), based on container type.

A more elegant approach, using a template meta-programming technique, is presented [by **Stephan T. Lavavej** here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-3-of-n#c634173340820000000).

Comment: It'll be much easier to write an overloaded `erase` when we have template constraints.

Comment: Note that this answer only describes erasing by value (or by properties of values). There is a uniform interface across all sequence and associative containers (except `array`) for erasing by iterator or iterator range.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Yes, I was focusing on erasing by value or property of values (which is common in code). I edited the question text to make it more clear. Thanks.

Comment: Good answer, just one little inaccuracy. The `std::map::erase` you present doesn't search for a whole value (key-value-pair), but only a key (which for maps is not the whole value). While this is indeed the usual use case, some clarification in the answer might be a good idea.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Thanks for the note. I've updated the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Perhaps adding link to [Iterator invalidation rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules) can be helpful. Since lots of people having problem with that, right after learning about how remove and erase work.

Comment: The "`std::vector` Pattern" applies to **any** sequence designated by a pair of random-access iterators. In general, containers are the wrong thing to focus on; iterators define an abstraction that should be the first approach to generic programming issues. Sometimes the iterator abstraction isn't sufficient, which is why `std::list`, which has bidirectional iterators, provides several member functions that do the same thing as generic algorithms that take random-access iterators.

Comment: You should point out that your erase loop for associative containers only works for C++11 and later.

Comment: For those worried about performance, the `remove` and `remove_if` idiom are ordered by shifting (using the move assignment). For removing several items from an `std::vector`, it is faster than iterating and removing each of them.

Comment: forgot to mention that `erase`/`remove` call the destructor of the element in the container (unless of course that element is a pointer); for completeness sake