# vector::erase causing strange behavior

Tags: c++, vector, erase, allegro

I am trying to create a vertically scrolling shooter where when you press space a bullet is created and then when the bullet goes off screen the bullet is destroyed. I keep track of the bullets through vector delcared as `vector<BULLET> bullets;` When I try to destroy any bullets that are outside of the screen, I get a ton of errors such as:
`c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h|384|  required from '_OI std::__copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = true; _II = BULLET*; _OI = BULLET*]'|`

**My code looks like this:**

```
for( auto it = bullets.begin(); it != bullets.end(); ){
    if( it->is_dead()){
        it = bullets.erase(it);
    }else{
        it++;
    }
}
```

The part that's frustrating me is that I have similar loop that deletes any game objects that need to be deleted in a vector that holds pointers with:

```
for( auto it = activeInstances.begin(); 
it != activeInstances.end(); ){
    if( (*it)->is_dead()){
        it = activeInstances.erase(it);
    }else{
        it++;
    }
}
```

and this one works just fine.

**Edit:** I'm not sure if it makes a difference or not but just for reference I'm adding the section that occurs later in the same function that adds bullets to the vector:

```
if( key[SPACE] && reload == 0){
    reload = reloadTime;
    BULLET newBullet;
    newBullet.init( x, y);
    bullets.push_back( newBullet);
}
```

Comment: Does BULLET have a move constructor?

Comment: Maybe you should replace  if( it->is_dead()){ with exactly the same code from bellow loop  if( (*it)->is_dead()){ ... You must access object in iterator and that you could do with *it

Comment: `it->` is valid to access the object of the iterator but if the objects in the vector itself is a point type, you'll have to go via `(*it)->` which in fact dereferences twice: the iterator and whatever type the iterator holds. Is BULLET a pointer type?

Comment: Did you have non-public copy or move constructors?

Comment: I did try chaning `it->is_dead()` to `(*it)->is_dead()` just to make sure that wasn't the problem and that throws an error because bullets is a vector of BULLET and activeInstances is a vector of *OBJECT

Comment: The problem WAS that I didn't have a move constructor for BULLET. I didn't even know what that was, but after I read about it, it makes sense. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

your code fragements differ:

```
if( it->is_dead()){
```

vs.

```
if( (*it)->is_dead()){
```

Comment: So do the the vectors that are being used by these snippets. This is by itself not the problem.

Comment: you're right, the definition of `BULLET` is crucial, but the code diff hints to a probable cause of the error.

Comment: If you could elaborate on that last statement collapsar I would really appreciate it. One is referencing a vector of objects and the other is referencing a vector of pointers to objects so that being the only difference in the code shouldn't be causing any problems, right?

Comment: @JustinMcFall: you didn't provide the definition of BULLET but stressed the analogy to the code segment with `activeInstances`. Glad you could sort out your problem following doctorlove's hint.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the **erase-remove idiom** to remove items from `std::vector` 
(you can consider [this StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16013545/how-do-i-erase-elements-from-stl-containers) for a detailed discussion, also applied to other containers):

> ```
> // Erase elements matching "erasing_condition" from vector "v"
> v.erase( std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), erasing_condition), v.end() );
> ```

In your particular case, you may want to use some code like this:

```
//
// Erase elements matching "BULLET.is_dead()" from vector "bullets".
// ("bullets" is a "vector<BULLET>")
//
bullets.erase
(     
    std::remove_if
    ( 
        bullets.begin(), 
        bullets.end(), 

        // Erasing condition
        [](const BULLET& bullet)
        { 
            return bullet.is_dead(); 
        }   
    ), 
    bullets.end() 
);
```

---

BTW: As a *style guide*, I'd prefer `Bullet` instead of `BULLET` for a C++ class name (`ALL_UPPERCASE_STYLE` is usually reserved for preprocessor macros in C++...).

Comment: I do appreciate the style guide very much, I agree that would be much better. I also tried your suggestion and still errors are thrown. The first one is new and is:
**stl_algo.h 1158** `error: no match for 'operator=' in '__result.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator*<BULLET*, std::vector<BULLET> >() = std::move<BULLET&>((* & __first.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator*<BULLET*, std::vector<BULLET> >()))'
candidate is: BULLET& BULLET::operator=(BULLET&)`

After that I get the same error as in OP flagged at the final line of bullets.erase

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as someone mentioned in one of the comments, was that I wasn't using a move constructor in my BULLET class (I'm a total noob and didn't even know what that was until it was mentioned). I really appreciate everyone's help though, I actually learned a lot!