# Vector of pointers element deletion

Tags: c++, vector, delete-operator

I have a vector of pointers and I want to delete an entry. After I delete the entry, I check the size of the vector and it is not reduced. Should I do an extra thing?

```
printf("size of vector before %d \n", m_obj.size());
for(std::vector<object*>::iterator it = m_obj.begin(); it != m_obj.end(); ++it)
{
  if((*it)->m_id == p_id)
  {
     delete *it;
  }
}

printf("size of vector after %d \n", m_obj.size());
```

Comment: Use `std::remove_if`, as well as smart pointers so you don't have to manually free them.

Comment: You're only deleting the actual pointer, you're not removing anything from the vector. After the loop, you have a vector of pointers, where some of the pointers now are invalid.

Comment: You are deleting the memory the pointer in your vector is pointing to. You are not removing the entry in the vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `delete *it` merely deletes the object *pointed to* by that entry in your vector. You do not modify the vector itself.

To also remove the element from the vector, make use of the [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) method:

```
 delete *it;
 it = m_obj.erase(it);
```

Note that erasing invalidates the current iterator, so you will probably want to assign the return value of the `erase` call to your `it` variable. Be careful not to accidentally skip elements when erasing more than one entry in a loop though. The returned iterator will point to the element *after* the one that was deleted and will get incremented *again* by the `for` loop.

The easiest way to get rid of this issue is to use an [STL algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) for removing the elements instead. This works best if the entries also have ownership of their pointees, so you might want to consider using vector of [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) instead (as suggested [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23064016/vector-of-pointers-element-deletion/23064134#comment35244595_23064016)), so you don't have to worry about explicitly calling `delete` at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
           +----------+         +-------------+
           | object * |-------->| heap memory |
           +----------+         +-------------+
it-------->| object * |-------->| heap memory |
           +----------+         +-------------+
           | object * |-------->| heap memory |
           +----------+         +-------------+
           | object * |-------->| heap memory |
           +----------+         +-------------+
```

After `delete *it`:

```
           +----------+         +-------------+
           | object * |-------->| heap memory |
           +----------+         +-------------+
it-------->| object * |-------->
           +----------+         +-------------+
           | object * |-------->| heap memory |
           +----------+         +-------------+
           | object * |-------->| heap memory |
           +----------+         +-------------+
```

You also need to somehow erase the pointer element in your vector. Keep in mind that you can't do `erase(it)` during the iteration since it invalidates your iterator.

Answer (score 0):

You are only freeing memory allocated under the pointer. You're not removing the pointer itself.

After you call delete, set the value of pointer to NULL. After your for loop use `std::remove_if` with NULL check on elements.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the object will not remove the pointer to it from the vector, it will only free the memory pointed to by the pointer. You will need to explicitly call `erase` on the vector after the element is freed.

Comment: m_obj.erase(it);//Like this?

Comment: @AvbAvb precisely. Just keep in mind that erase from the vector may invalidate the iterators to it, so the cycle may break. You need to erase the element after the cycle completes.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Not exactly. See ComicSansMS's answer.

Comment: @ooga yeap that's another option.

Answer (score 0):

Having an STL container (e.g. `std::vector`) of **owning** **raw** pointers is in general a bad idea. This can be a source of *leaktrocity*: e.g. if an exception is thrown somewhere, the vector destructor is called, but that will *not* delete the raw owning pointers! So their associated resources are leaked.
Moreover you have to provide explicit cleanup code, etc.

You may want to either use `std::vector<Object>`, or a `std::vector` of **smart pointers**, e.g. `vector<shared_ptr<Object>>` or `vector<unique_ptr<Object>>` (the latter available since C++11 thanks to move semantics, and a good solution if the `vector` is the *unique* owner of the objects, and there is no shared ownership).

You may also want to use *algorithms* like **`remove_if()`**. In particular, to remove items satisfying some precise condition from `vector`, you may want to use the so called **erase-remove idiom**:

```
// Use a vector of *smart pointers* (shared_ptr or unique_ptr).
typedef std::shared_ptr<Object> ObjectPtr;
std::vector<ObjectPtr> v;

...
...

// Use the erase-remove idiom to erase items satisfying a particular condition.
v.erase( std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](const ObjectPtr & p) { 
    return p->m_id == deleteId; // Erasing condition 
}), v.end());
```

The make the code clearer (especially if one doesn't know/recognize the erase-remove idiom), it's possible to write a little helper function to implement this idiom:

```
// Helper function to implement the erase-remove idiom for std::vector.
template <typename T, typename Predicate>
void erase_if(std::vector<T>& v, Predicate p) {
    v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), p), v.end());
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
// Simplified code: just pass the vector 'v' and the erasing condition
// (in this case using a simple lambda).
// Uses the erase-remove idiom under the hood.
//
erase_if(v, [&](const ObjectPtr & p) { return p->m_id == deleteId; });
```

Note that thanks to the use of the `remove_if` *algorithm* and the erase-remove idiom, the *semantic level* of your code is raised: you don't read explicit `for` loops and iterator incrementing anymore; you can just read the clear *intent* of the code, i.e. erasing items that satisfy a given condition.

---

**PS**: You might also want to read: ["How do I erase elements from STL containers?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16013545/1629821).