# C++ remove certain elements of vector

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array, stl, erase

I am new to C++ and want to do vector element elimination.

My vectors are like:

```
<vector<vector>> objPoints;
<vector<vector>> delPoints;
<vector<vector>> objPoints2;
```

each objPoints has size 1000x3 and has all points. From objPoints i want to remove delPoints i.e. the (X,Y,Z) values that reside in each row.

Can anyone please tell me syntax?

Comment: What type is Your inner vector?

Comment: If you want to be able to delete elements then `std::vector` was probably not a good design choice for your container.

Comment: @MaksimGorkiy: it has just co-ordinate values. in x y z direction. Outer vector is to have same xyz values multiple times. so outer 1000, inner 3.

Comment: Well i meant if they are `int` or some `float` type, since it might be important when You are going to compare them

Comment: Can you give a more elaborate example? What do you mean by "the (X,Y,Z) values that reside in each row."

Comment: @MaksimGorkiy: sry about that. Yeah they are int values.

Answer (score 2):

I interpret your questions as follows: You have two vectors `objPoints` and `delPoints` which contain 1000 three-dimensional points. I would encode this as

`std::vector<std::array<int,3> > objPoints;`

where I assumed you have some raster such that you can desribe your points by `int` values (otherwise, for `double` entries, comparison is not that easy).

One benefit of using `std::array<int,3>` is that you automatically get a lexicographic ordering of the points (that means, specializations of `std::less` and `std::equal_to` which can directly be used without the further need to create some).

---

**Algorithm:**

First sort your arrays. There might be algorithms where this is not really necessary (see the other answer by @AshwaniDausodia), but the following assumes it. Further, in general by using sorted vectors one can obtain a better performance (at least in the big-O: for unsorted containers, it is roughly `O(size1*size2)`, whereas it is lower for the following algorithm). The sorting first requires an effort of `O(size1 log(size1)) + O(size2 log(size2))`

Next, traverse both arrays at the same time and each time you find a common element delete it from one of the vectors. As you traverse sorted arrays, where you can always increase only the iterator pointing to the smaller element, this step takes `O(size1+size2)`.

---

**Implementation:**

```
// deletes the elements from container c1 which are also present in c2
// requires sorted containers c1 and c2
//
template< class ContainerType1, class ContainerType2 >
void delete_common_elements(ContainerType1& c1, ContainerType2 const& c2 )
{
    for(auto it1=c1.begin(), it2=c2.begin()
       ; it1!=c1.end() && it2!=c2.end(); )
    {
        if(*it1==*it2)  // eventually change here if your points are not int's
                        // but are of floating-point type
        {
             it1 = c1.erase(it1);  //it1 is increased here
        }
        else
        {
             *it1<*it2 ? ++it1 : ++it2;
        }
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/258c2fe91ac7b708)

All together, this requires an effort of `O(c1.size()) + O(c1.size() * log(c1.size())` (naturally assuming `c1.size()>=c2.size()`).

One can easily extend this to take an arbitrary comparison operator instead of the `operator==`.

Comment: Doesn't `c1.erase(it1);` cause it1 to be invalid?

Comment: @ikh: no, but thanks for the comment. It causes that `it1` is increased, so my algo needs to be corrected. Done.

Comment: @davidhigh My answer requires array to be sorted. I think you did't read it till end.

Comment: @davidhigh maybe that's the result of invalid iterator - iterator of `std::vector` may be implemented as just pointer, so `it1` can point the next position after `c1.erase(it1);`

Comment: @AshwaniDausodia: you're right, I read only the first algorithm (which works also for unsorted containers). The next algorithm indeed looks quite identical to the one above. Sorry.

Comment: @ihk: actually, I had to change it again: `it1 = c1.erase(it1)` is the correct code.

Comment: How can you sort a vector of 3D points? What comparison function would you use for the 3D points?

Comment: @Mr.C64: you can use any *weak ordering*. Particularly, in case of 3D points `(x,y,z)`, you can use [lexicographic ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order): `(x1,y1,z1)<(x2,y2,z2) <=> x1<x2 || (x1==x2 && y1<y2) || (x1==x2 && y1==y2 && z1<z2) `. This is what `std::array<int,3>` does.

Answer (score 0):

If you definately have to use vectors, an easy (but inefficient) way would be to `std::find` the element in objPoints that you want to remove and then remove it with `std::vector::erase`.

Answer (score 0):

One obivious method would be:

```
for each point in delPoints
    if point exists in objPoints
        delete point from objPoints.
```

You can do it much more efficiently if you are allowed to sort the vectors. I will provide you with method and pseudo code then you can implement it on you own.

```
First sort objPoints and delpoints
i=0,j=0
while i < length(objPoints) and j < length(delPoints)
    if objPoints[i] > delPoints[j]       // Means delPoints[j] is not there in objPoints. If it would have, we would have found it.
        j++
    else if objPoints[i] < delPoints[j]  // Means delPoints[j] is after objPoints[i] if it is there in objPoints
        i++
    else
        erase objPoints[i]           // Means we have found delPoints[j], so delete it.
```

For comaprison, first compare w.r.t `x cordinate` then `y` and then `z`. For sorting, you can use `std::sort` with same comparison function described in previous line. For deleting, you can use `std::vector::erase`.
 Or you can implement your own fuctions.

Comment: why should i check which elements are greater in objPoints than delPoints. Let me reframe. I have list of points in objPoints which is in excess. I have a list of Points those i want to eliminate (delPoints). At the end as a result i want objPoints2 which does not have delPoints. Also what you have written under Method is pretty straight forward and i had that in mind. Coding is difficult for me :(

Comment: I have added comments to make it more clear. And be specific where are you facing difficulties in coding (means in sorting or in comparing).

Answer (score 0):

You may consider read [this Q&A on StackOverflow on how to erase elements from STL containers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16013545/1629821).

The key point is to use the *erase-remove idiom* to erase items from the vector, and use a lambda to express the erasing condition:

```
objPoints.erase(
    std::remove_if(
        objPoints.begin(), 
        objPoints.end(), 
        [&delPoints](const Point3D& point)
        { 
            // Erasing condition:
            // Is 'point' contained in the 'delPoints' vector?
            auto it = std::find(delPoints.begin(), delPoints.end(), point);
            return (it != delPoints.end());
        }), 
    objPoints.end());
```

Full compilable code sample ([**live here**](http://ideone.com/L1NnhA)):

```
#include <algorithm>    // for std::find(), std::remove_if()
#include <array>        // for std::array
#include <iostream>     // for console output
#include <vector>       // for std::vector

typedef std::array<int, 3> Point3D;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point3D& point)
{
    os << "{" << point[0] << ", " 
       << point[1] << ", " << point[2] << "}";

    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<Point3D>& v) 
{
    if (v.empty())
    {
        os << "{ <empty> }" << std::endl;
        return os;
    }

    os << "{\n";
    for (const auto& point : v)
    {
        os << "  " << point << '\n';
    }
    os << "}" << std::endl;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Point3D> objPoints{{1, 2, 3}, 
                                   {4, 5, 6}, 
                                   {11, 22, 33}, 
                                   {44, 55, 66}, 
                                   {77, 88, 99}};

    std::vector<Point3D> delPoints{{10, 10, 10}, 
                                   {11, 22, 33}, 
                                   {44, 55, 66}};


    std::cout << "objPoints =\n" << objPoints << std::endl;
    std::cout << "delPoints =\n" << delPoints << std::endl;

    objPoints.erase(
        std::remove_if(
            objPoints.begin(), 
            objPoints.end(), 
            [&delPoints](const Point3D& point)
            { 
                // Erasing condition:
                // Is 'point' contained in the 'delPoints' vector?
                auto it = std::find(delPoints.begin(), delPoints.end(), point);
                return (it != delPoints.end());
            }), 
        objPoints.end());

    std::cout << "\nAfter erasing, objPoints =\n";
    std::cout << objPoints << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> objPoints =
> {
>   {1, 2, 3}
>   {4, 5, 6}
>   {11, 22, 33}
>   {44, 55, 66}
>   {77, 88, 99}
> }
>
> delPoints =
> {
>   {10, 10, 10}
>   {11, 22, 33}
>   {44, 55, 66}
> }
>
>
> After erasing, objPoints =
> {
>   {1, 2, 3}
>   {4, 5, 6}
>   {77, 88, 99}
> }
> ```