# how to implement a for_each like function in c++?

Tags: c++, vector, stl-algorithm

I need to implement a `for_each` function, like below. I know `std::for_each` could apply `fn` to each element, but we cannot erase elements in `std::for_each`. I need to extend this template function, so that **in `fn`, the caller can both visit elements and erase elements one at a time**.  Is there a proper way to do this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
    explicit A(){
        mVec.clear();
    }
    ~A(){}
    template<class T> void for_each(T fn)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < mVec.size(); ++i)
        {
            //fn can erase element or just visit element
            fn(mVec[i]);
        }
    }
    vector<int> mVec;
};
int main()
{
    A test;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        test.mVec.push_back(i);
    }
    test.for_each([&test](int i){
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            cout << i << " deleted" << endl;
            test.mVec.erase(find(test.mVec.begin(), test.mVec.end(), i));
        } 
        else
        {
            cout << i << " parse" << endl;
        }
    });

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: In `for_each` template function, we do not know whether the caller will erase elements or not. Erasing elements is done in `fn`

Comment: try `vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](int i){ return i%2==0;}), vec.end());`  ?

Comment: Use `std::remove_if`. Also see the "remove-erase idiom".

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16013545/how-do-i-erase-elements-from-stl-containers) on how to properly remove items from a vector.

Comment: This thread is interesting and related, on why the elements are immutable in foreach. Don't be fooled by the c-sharp in the topic - it's actually about the design of foreach and is interesting regardless of implementation language. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776430/why-is-the-iteration-variable-in-a-c-sharp-foreach-statement-read-only

Answer (score 4):

Could you return a `bool` value from the function, where `true` means "erase the element"? Then your for_each function becomes something like.

```
    size_t i = 0;
    for(size_t j = 0; j < mVec.size(); ++j) {
        if (!fn(mVec[j])) {
            // The element must be kept
            if (i != j)
                mVec[i] = std::move(mVec[j]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    mVec.resize(i);
```

The advantage is also that this is always O(n), no matter how many elements are erased.

*EDIT*: The loop above is really just std::remove_if(), so @ChenOT's suggestion is the best.  Alternatively

```
    n = std::remove_if(mVec.begin(), mVec.end(), fn) - mVec.begin();
    mVec.resize(n);
```

Comment: You buried the lede here, which is that this method is O(n) instead of O(n^2) as when you erase single elements from a vector.  +1.

Comment: @JohnZwinck, the same will hold for remove_if too though.

Comment: @PaoloBonzini, thanks. But this will not help. When we use remove_if function, We control the delete operation. if someone erase a element in fn, running crashes. I want to implement a public template function, the caller can erase elements or visit elements in fn one at a time.

Comment: @IceYounger, it's impossible to solve what you want in a generic way, or it would be solved. Try rephrasing your problem in terms of remove_if.

Comment: @PaoloBonzini, thanks. Maybe we can let fn return a bool value. If fn erase an element, return true, then iterator stop auto-incrementing. If return false, auto-increment.

Comment: @IceYounger Then what you have is exactly something that can be passed to remove_if. :)